# Given an array V, we need to find two indices (i,j) such that V[j] > V[i] and (j - i) is maximum

Tags: algorithm

Given an array V, we need to find two indices (i,j) such that V[j] > V[i] and (j - i) is maximum.

The brute force approach is pretty straight forward wherein for each value at index i (ranging from 1 to n), we compare value at index j (ranging from i+1 to n). We keep track of maximum (j-i) so far to find the final answer.

This approach has the time complexity of O(n^2). Does anybody have any suggestions on improving the time complexity?

Comment: @spacevillain Your approach would not work if the list is [4, 3, 2 ,1 ], because after sorting it in non-decreasing order, `i` will be 3 and `j` be 0,  which is incorrect since `j` should be greater than `i`.

Comment: @Kay, what is limitation of V[i]?

Comment: @IvanBenko - There are no constraints on the values of the array if that is what you are referring. All we have to find is a pair of indices(i,j) such that A[j] > A[i], and j-i is maximum (maximized).

Comment: [8, 7, 5, 4, 2, 1, 9, 6, 3] is a really tricky list to search.

Comment: I can find a good lower limit for `j - i` in O(n). First, find two consecutive entries in ascending order. Then, work back from the end of the array, looking for an entry greater than the lower entry. Then, work back from the lower entry, looking for an entry lower than the upper entry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Algorithm with O(N) complexity:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

sub dump_list { print join(", ", map sprintf("%2d", $_), @_), "\n" }

for (0..20) {
    # generate a random list of integers with some convenient bias:
    my @l = (map int(rand(20) + 20 - $_), 0..19);

    my $max = $l[-1];
    my $min = $l[0];

    my @max;
    for my $l (reverse @l) {
        $max = $l if $l > $max;
        push @max, $max;
    }
    @max = reverse @max;

    my @min;
    for my $l (@l) {
        $min = $l if $l < $min;
        push @min, $min;
    }

    my $best_i = 0;
    my $best_j = -1;
    my $best   = -1;

    my $j = 0;
    for my $i (0..$#l) {
        while ($j < @l) {
            last unless $max[$j] > $min[$i];
            $j++;
            if ($j - $i > $best) {
                $best = $j - 1 - $i;
                $best_i = $i;
                $best_j = $j - 1;
            }
        }
    }

    print "list: "; dump_list @l;
    print "idxs: "; dump_list 0..$#l;
    print "best: $best, i: $best_i, j: $best_j\n\n";
}
```

**update**: in response to Nohsib request:

Say you have a random list of numbers (a[0], a[1], a[2], a[3]..., a[N-1])

First step is to find for every number the maximum to the left as mas `max[i] = maximum(a[0], a[1], ..., a[i])` and the minimum to the right `min[i] = minimum(a[i], a[i+1], ..., a[N-1])`.

Once you have those arrays finding the interval where `a[j] < a[k]` that maximizes `k-j` is almost trivial.

Try doing it in paper with some random lists and you will easily find out the logic behind.

Comment: Brilliant! I guess this would still work if instead of using for and while loop, you have a single while loop like `while ( i < n & j < n)` and increment `j` when `$max[$j] > $min[$i]` else increment `i`. Currently with your approach, you may still get a time complexity of O(n^2) for a list like `[1,2,3,4,4,4,4,4,4,4]`. But with the above suggested change you can reduce the time complexity to O(n). Thanks for the idea. I would try to write up the pseudo code when I get sometime.

Comment: @Kay: it is already O(N) in the worst case because `$j` is not reset to 0 inside the for loop. In the worst case the code inside the while loop is executed 2*N times, and so it is O(N).

Answer (score 3):

Here's an approach that will solve the problem in linear time.

1. Compute the stack S of increasing positions `i` such that `min A[1..i-1] > i` with a simple forwards scan over the array.
2. Iterate over the list backwards.
3. While the current element is greater than the value given by the top of the stack S: check if we have a new record and pop the top of the stack.

A quick implementation in python:

```
def notsurewhattonamethis(A):
    assert(A)
    S = [0]
    for i,v in enumerate(A):
        if v<A[S[-1]]:
            S.append(i)
    best = (-1,-1)
    for i,v in reversed(list(enumerate(A))):
        while v>A[S[-1]]:
            j = S.pop()
            d = i - j
            if d > best[1]-best[0]:
                best = (j,i)
            if not S: return best
    return best
```

Comment: Nice, although it's still O(N^2) time*space complexity.

Comment: @Neil: Why would you be concerned with time*space complexity anyway?

Comment: Only because it the original question didn't clarify whether O(N) space complexity was acceptable. (Given the accepted answer, I see it is.)

Answer (score 2):

If you have known limitation of array elements **(else see update below)** I can suggest you algorithm with time complexity `O(n*log(MaxN))` and space complexity O(MaxN) where MaxN = Max(V[i]).
For this algorithm we need structure that can get minimum in array between 1 and N with time complexity O(log(N)) and update array element with time complexity O(log(N)). [Fenwick tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fenwick_tree) can do those tricks. Let's call this structure **minimizator**. Then we need to:

1. Iterate all elements in given order v[i] and put at v[i] position at minimizator value i.
2. For each element v[i] find minimum using minimizator between 1 and v[i-1] (this is minimum index of element that less than v[i])
3. Remember maximum difference between i and found minimum index of element that less than v[i].

Ok. I've tried to write some **pseudocode**:

```
prepare array (map values)
init minimizator

ansI = -1
ansJ = -1

for i from 0 to v.length-1
  minIndexOfElementLessThanCurrent = get min value from 1 to v[i]-1 (inclusive) using minimizator
  set to minimizator v[i] position value i

  if minIndexOfElementLessThanCurrent is exists
    if ansJ - ansI < i - minIndexOfElementLessThanCurrent 
      ansJ = i
      ansI = minIndexOfElementLessThanCurrent
```

C++ implementation:

```
class FenwickTree
{
    vector<int> t;
    int n;

public:

    static const int INF = 1000*1000*1000;

    void Init (int n)
    {
        this->n = n;
        t.assign (n, INF);
    }

    int GetMin (int i)
    {
        int res = INF;
        for (; i >= 0; i = (i & (i+1)) - 1)
            res = min (res, t[i]);
        return res;
    }

    void Update (int i, int value)
    {
        for (; i < n; i = (i | (i+1)))
            t[i] = min (t[i], value);
    }
};

pair<int, int> Solve(const vector<int>& v)
{
    int maxElement = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < v.size(); i++)
        maxElement = max(maxElement, v[i]);

    FenwickTree minimizator;
    minimizator.Init(maxElement+1);

    int ansI = -1, ansJ = -1;
    for(int i = 0; i < v.size(); i++)
    {
        int minLeftIndex = minimizator.GetMin(v[i]-1);      
        minimizator.Update(v[i], i);

        if(minLeftIndex == FenwickTree::INF) continue; // no left elements less than v[i]

        if(ansJ - ansI < i - minLeftIndex)
        {           
            ansJ = i;
            ansI = minLeftIndex;
        }
    }
    return make_pair(ansI, ansJ);
}
```

**UPDATE:**
If kind of elements is not int(f.e. double) or if max value of array elements is too big (f.e. 10^9) we can 
map array values **(it will not affect the result)** to integer set 1..N and then time complexity should be **O(n * log(n))**

**UPDATE:**

If elements is integer - there is `O(max(maxN, n))` solution. So if `maxN <= n` complexity is **O(N)**. We just need to answer for the query 'get minimum from 1 to N' in const time O(1):

1. Create array of size `maxN`
2. Element m[i] of array is minimum index of `i` value in source array V.
3. Using dynamic programming create array the same size that element `r[i]` of array is minimum of `m[j], 1 <= j <= i`. Recurrence relation is `r[i] = min(r[i-1], m[i])`

Main idea of this algorithm is the same as above, only use array `r` to find min from `1` to `v[i]`.

```
C++ implementation:

pair<int, int> Solve(const vector<int>& v)
{
    int maxElement = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < v.size(); i++)
        maxElement = max(maxElement, v[i]);

    vector<int> minimum(maxElement + 1, v.size() + 1);
    for(int i = 0; i < v.size(); i++)
        minimum[v[i]] = min(minimum[v[i]], i); // minimum[i] contains minimum index of element i

    for(int i = 1; i < minimum.size(); i++)
        minimum[i] = min(minimum[i-1], minimum[i]); // now minimum[i] contains minimum index between elements 1 and i

    int ansI = -1, ansJ = -1;
    for(int i = 0; i < v.size(); i++)
    {
        int minLeftIndex = minimum[v[i]-1];      

        if(minLeftIndex >= i) continue; // no left elements less than v[i]

        if(ansJ - ansI < i - minLeftIndex)
        {           
            ansJ = i;
            ansI = minLeftIndex;
        }
    }
    return make_pair(ansI, ansJ);
}
```

If elements are double, or something else (very big integers) we cannot map elements to set 1..N in linear time (or can?). I know only `O(n*log(n))` solution (sorting elements, etc)

Comment: +1 for algo, almost -1 for poor implementation. Better write it in pseudocode

Answer (score 2):

Java implementation runs in linear time.

```
public class MaxIndexDifference {

public static void main(String[] args) {
     System.out.println(betweenTwoElements(2, 3, 6, 10, 4));
}

private static int betweenTwoElements(int... nums) {
    int numberOfElements = nums.length;
    int maxDifference = -1, minIndex = 0, maxIndex = 0;

    int[] lMin = new int[numberOfElements];
    int[] rMax = new int[numberOfElements];

    /* Construct lMin such that stores the minimum value (to the left)  from (nums[0], nums[1], ... nums[i])*/

    lMin[0] = nums[0];
    for (int i = 1; i < numberOfElements; i++) {
        lMin[i] = Math.min(nums[i], lMin[i -1]);
    }
    /* Construct RMax[] such that RMax[j] stores the maximum value (to the right) from (arr[j], arr[j+1], ..arr[n-1]) */
    rMax[numberOfElements - 1] = nums[numberOfElements - 1];
    for (int i = numberOfElements-2; i >= 0; i--) {
        rMax[i] =  Math.max(nums[i], rMax[i + 1]);
    }
    /* Traverse both arrays from left to right to find optimum maxIndex - minIndex This process is similar to merge() of MergeSort */
    while (minIndex < numberOfElements && maxIndex < numberOfElements) {
        if (lMin[minIndex] < rMax[maxIndex]) {
            maxDifference = Math.max(maxDifference, maxIndex - minIndex);
            maxIndex = maxIndex +1;
        } else {
            minIndex = minIndex +1;
        }           
    }   
    return maxDifference;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you actually want here, the first paragraph of your question conflicts with the second. So I'll give two answers, one for each interpretation that I can think of, although both may not be what you meant.

The first interpretation: searching for a maximal V[j]-V[i], under the constraint that j > i.
This is that it's *almost* finding the min and max. But in addition, there's also a constraint on the indexes. That in itself doesn't mean that the idea can't be used; for any chosen V[i], you just need the max over V[i+1 .. n], and you don't need to recompute those maxes every time, leading to this algorithm:

- Compute the suffix-max array in O(n)
- Find the pair (V[i],suffixmax[i+1]) with maximal difference in O(n)

The second interpretation: searching for a maximal j-i, under the constraint that V[j] > V[i].
I can't come up with anything good.